# How to deal with Non-ASCII Warning when performing Save on Python code edited with IDLE?

Tags: python, windows, python-idle, non-ascii-characters, cp1252

I frequently edit Python code using IDLE and occasionally when I perform a Save I receive an I/O Warning.

[image]

I am assuming that I have inadvertently added a Non-ASCII character, and I do not really want to declare the cp1252 encoding.

Is there an easy way to find and delete the Non-ASCII that the Warning relates to?

The OS Version involved is Windows 7, and the Python version is 2.6.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `[^ -~]` will match anything except printing ASCII characters. It should be able to find your stray non-ASCII character.

Use it with IDLE's Search dialogue (Ctrl + F, or Edit → Find); it can search by regex:

[image: search]

Comment: Can you elaborate just a little on how to use regex in this instance?

Comment: Use IDLE's Search dialogue. I've added a clarification.