# I/O Warning Non ASCII found

Tags: python, syntax

This is my first question...

I just checked this [How to deal with Non-ASCII Warning when performing Save on Python code edited with IDLE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270174/how-to-deal-with-non-ascii-warning-when-performing-save-on-python-code-edited-wi)
but didn't find the solution.

I wrote a very little code with idle and i save it. I call the file from the shell with python 3 and this image arrives.

Sorry for my english, and if i make this questions wrong.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TC79o.png)

Comment: In image its already mentioned what to do. You need to add first line in your code file as "# -\*- coding: utf-8 -\*-"

Comment: Yes i tryed it. But idle give me syntax error. I check my code. Damn i'm a noob.

Comment: # -\*- coding: utf-8 -\*-

Comment: Can you paste here what you wrote in first line? First Char should be #.

Comment: I deleted the # damn! Thanks!!

Comment: Added separate answer, so in future others can also directly check solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In image its already mentioned what to do.

You need to add first line in your code file as "**# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-**"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```